# Translation of '아무렴 그렇지, 그렇고 말고'

Tags: translation

I think '아무렴 그렇지, 그렇고 말고' was a [TV show back in the 80s](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%95%84%EB%AC%B4%EB%A0%B4_%EA%B7%B8%EB%A0%87%EC%A7%80,_%EA%B7%B8%EB%A0%87%EA%B3%A0_%EB%A7%90%EA%B3%A0). I'm not sure if it's a common expression beyond that.

I am having trouble getting a handle on what it means. '아무렴 그렇지' seems to be something like 'Of course it's like that...' but I'm not sure about 그렇고 말고. Can someone break it down for me?

Comment: If I understand correctly, 아무렴 is an abbreviation of 아무려면, which means "if you want to be in anyway".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

그렇고 말고 is something like "yes definately it is."

And 아무렴 그렇지, 그렇고 말고 is lylics of old traditional song - 한 오백년. I think the drama's title is also from the song.

Comment: Is 아무렴 그렇지, 그렇고 말고 also the song title?

Comment: The title is 한 오백년.

Comment: I quite like that one. I am learning about 조용필 and 오빠부대...